# How can I distribute a WCF Peer to Peer application over the Internet?

Tags: .net, wcf, p2p

Can someone point me in the right direction? I wish to distribute a WCF peer to peer cloud over the internet. So far I've seen examples of how it works on the same subnet. I wish to push it a little further.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you'll need to look into using [IPV6 Teredo Tunneling](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/network/ipv6/teredo.mspx) for crossing NAT and firewalls, so maybe check out this on [WCF transports](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731948.aspx) from MSDN.

Also, take a look at the [PRNP series](http://dotnetaddict.dotnetdevelopersjournal.com/tags/?/peerseries) Kevn Hoffman did this year.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your application you may want to check out [Groove Virtual Office](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/groove/FX100487641033.aspx?ofcresset=1), which was recently acquired by Microsoft and shipped with Office 2007.  I don't believe it uses WCF, but it certainly uses .NET and has an [SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=BAA487E9-E1B9-4A10-BEEA-1FD906B77F92&displaylang=en) available that should allow you to create a P2P application with ease.

If you are developing for the enterprise, be prepared to deal with scalability problems.

Answer (score 0):

I will look into Live Mesh, it may be the solution to my problem.

Answer (score 0):

So even though this is a year later...

Haven't you tried out the One click deployment method? Or what about just having the MSI install package for download? Is the deployment or the communication that you are trying to solve. Sounds like a distribution problem.

The method for getting pat NAT problems is called "Nat Traversal".

Comment: no this is not a distribution problem. the problem is related to the actual technology. the peer to peer binding is limited to a subnet.

Comment: So basically you want to connect peers from behind a NAT? Well then you're in a for a good time. So WCF doesn't natively support this (as I've come to realize) which means that you either have to use UPnP or implement NAT Traversal (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NAT_traversal) to get the peers to communicate. Interestingly enough I'm also delving into this area to write a library for c# that would be able to do this. Perhaps we should collaborate?